# How to read strings from stdin into a two-dimensional array in c programming using scanf() and while loop?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm writing a c code to read strings from stdin with scanf() and while loop (into a two-dimensional char array). My strategy is to use an input array to temporarily store each string and then assign it to a preword array (fixed sized). However, my strategy failed and all strings stored in my arrays are the same (the last string input). How to fix it?

I used a fgets() and it works find. However, I cannot use it to deal with a new line of strings (from stdin). My fgets() reads only the first line and that's why I turn to scanf and while loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 1000
#define size 50


int main ()
{
  int count = 0;
  char input[size];
  char * preword[MAX];
  while (scanf("%s",input)!= EOF){
    preword[count] = input;
    printf("preword[%d] is %s\n",count,preword[count]);
    count++;

  }
  printf("the count is %d\n",count);

  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    printf("preword[%d] is %s\n",i,preword[i]);
  }
  return 0;

}
```

I expect my input arrays from stdin will be stored in a two-dimensional char array. Below is the output in terminal after compilation. My input is a txt file, in which I have

```
hello world 
I am a hero
```

It turns out that all strings stored in the two-d array are the last word.

```
preword[0] is hello
preword[1] is world
preword[2] is I
preword[3] is am
preword[4] is a
preword[5] is hero
the count is 6
preword[0] is hero
preword[1] is hero
preword[2] is hero
preword[3] is hero
preword[4] is hero
preword[5] is hero
```

Comment: You are storing a pointer to the `input` buffer in every element.  It's the same pointer.  You should `malloc` enough memory for each string and use `strcpy`.

Comment: In a pinch: `preword[count] = malloc(strlen(input)+1); if (preword[count]) strcpy(preword[count, input);` -- you should include `<string.h>`.

Comment: It works! Thank you! FYI, is it possible to not have a fixed sized preword? My inputs files contain different number of strings and I feel that it's a waste of memory to use a fixed preword array.

Comment: Yes.  Read up on `malloc` and `realloc`.  Learn about efficiency of amortized versus linear growth.  Be careful with sizes.  Allocations are in _bytes_, not elements.  A single `char*` element occupies `sizeof(char*)` bytes.  Also learn about `free`.

Comment: Ummm, I keep doing the same thing and the result never changes? There is only one `input` -- where do you think everything will point if you are assigning the address of `input` to everything? And... what does `input` hold at the end? (the last string read `:)`

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation David, but please don't "honey" me... it's weird.

Comment: How's that? (less weird...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly here

```
char * preword[MAX];
```

`preword` is *array of character pointer* i.e each element is a char pointer & when you are doing like

```
preword[count] = input;
```

as @paddy pointed its copies `input` in every element of `preword` and *it's the same pointer since you haven't allocated memory for `preword[count]`*, correct way is to allocate memory for each pointer and then copy.

Also use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()` here. For e.g

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 1000
#define size 50
int main (void)
{
  int count = 0;
  char input[size] = {0};
  char * preword[MAX] = {0};
  size_t retStrCspn = 0;
  while (fgets(input, size, stdin) != NULL){
    /* remove trailing new line if its stored at end of buffer by fgets() */
    input[retStrCspn = strcspn(input, "\n")] = 0; /* remove the trailing & use the return value for allocating memory purpose \n */
    preword[count] = malloc(retStrCspn + 1); /* Allocate memory for each pointer elements */
    if(preword[count] != NULL) {
        memcpy (preword[count], input, retStrCspn + 1); /* copy input buffer into each different memory location */
        printf("preword[%d] is %s\n",count,preword[count]);
        count++;
    }
    else {
        /* @TODO malloc erro handling */
    }
  }
  printf("the count is %d\n",count);

  for (int i = 0; i < count && preword[i] != NULL; i++){
    printf("preword[%d] is %s\n",i,preword[i]);
    free(preword[count]); /* free dynamically allocated memory here*/
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, fgets works to get all strings in the stdin file. However, it stores each line in a char array instead of storing each word in a char array.

Comment: yes `fgets()` reads until `\n` and stored same into `preword[count]`. you can remove the trailing `\n` by using `strcspn` as I suggested.

Comment: How about `size_t len; input[(len = strcspn(input, "\n"))] = 0; preword[count] = malloc (len + 1); if (...) { memcpy (preword[count], input, len + 1);`?  That way you eliminate the fixed `size` and you can set `#define MAX 8192` (or however large you like) and read virtually any line you will encounter, and allocate only the required number of bytes to store what you read. ( and you can't `free(preword[count]);` until after you `printf("preword[%d] is %s\n",i,preword[i]);`

Comment: Agree @DavidC.Rankin yes that will be much better approach I guess, using return value of `strcspn()`

Comment: Since `strcspn` returns the initial number of characters not containing `'\n'` it provides the length when you use `"\n"` as the delimiter. Also see the note I added at the end about the location of `free(preword[count]);`

Comment: Agree. I should have kept `printf()` statement printing `preword` before calling `free`. Thanks @DavidC.Rankin for pointing the mistake & correcting.